# Compile `mysql_pdo` driver on RHEL 6 (no internet access, no `yum install`)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, pdo, makefile

I am having an extremely annoying problem with `pdo_mysql`.

Configuration:

- RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 x64 (**not connected to the internet**)
- PHP 5.6.21
- MariaDB 10.1.14

This is what I did:

- uninstalled the default `mysql` package and installed the `mariadb` (everything listed here: http://ftp.ddg.lth.se/mariadb//mariadb-10.1.14/yum/rhel6-amd64/rpms/ except the `oqgraph-engine.rpm`). I was able to query tables so I assume the installation is fine.
- running the web application I got an error saying `could not find driver` so I tried to compile the `php` `pdo_mysql` driver;
- for ease of access I placed the source files (the same files I used to install the `PHP`) at `/php-5.6.21`;
- I navigated to `/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql`, ran `phpize` followed by `./configure` and then `make`. Here I got a bunch of errors:

  ```
  [root@user029x ~]# cd /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql
  [root@user029x pdo_mysql]# phpize
  Configuring for:
  PHP Api Version:         20131106
  Zend Module Api No:      20131226
  Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
  [root@user029x pdo_mysql]# ./configure
  ......................................
  [root@user029x pdo_mysql]# make
  /bin/sh /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -I. -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c -o pdo_mysql.lo
   cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -I. -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_mysql.o
  In file included from /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:32:
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/php_pdo_mysql_int.h:27:34: error: ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.h: No such file or directory
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/php_pdo_mysql_int.h:28:50: error: ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_libmysql_compat.h: No such file or directory
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/php_pdo_mysql_int.h:64:39: error: ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_debug.h: No such file or directory
  In file included from /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:32:
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/php_pdo_mysql_int.h:101: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/php_pdo_mysql_int.h:116: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_FIELD’
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/php_pdo_mysql_int.h:121: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:61:45: error: ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h: No such file or directory
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:62: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:82: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘pdo_mysql_reverse_api’
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c: In function ‘zm_startup_pdo_mysql’:
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:132: error: ‘pdo_mysql_reverse_api’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:132: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
  /php-5.6.21/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c:132: error: for each function it appears in.)
  make: *** [pdo_mysql.lo] Error 1
  ```

I looked everywhere I could and checked similar posts here and on serverfault. I was not able to find a clear and conclusive answer to help me debug further. The consulted solutions suggested using `yum install` (which I cannot) or reinstalling everything (I really do not want to go through the whole process again...).

If needed here is a list with the modules I have installed so far using the above mentioned method:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
gd
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
oci8
pcre
PDO
PDO_OCI
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

Can you please help me figure this out?

---

**Edit:** `ext` and `mysqlnd` directories listed:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing, compiling a bundled extension as stand-alone, is not fully supported. But you should be able to work-around this.

For using MySQL modules in PHP there are two options: Either use libmysql or mysqlnd. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php and http://php.net/mysqlnd for background.

By default the build-system assumes you're using mysqlnd, but your system currently has no myslqnd installed. You have two options:

1. install mysqlnd first, then pdo_mysql
2. use libmysql

For 1) you go to ext/myslqnd and do the phpize, configure, make, make install steps there. Evetually phpize might complain, then you'd have to rename `config9.m4` in there to `config.m4` first. Once mysqlnd is installed you can go to pdo_mysql and do as you tried. It should now fid the correct headers.

For 2) you need libmysql including development headers installed on your system. Then you can run configure using the `--with-pdo-mysql=/usr` option, which tells where to find libmysql.

In general I'd suggest using mysqlnd using approach 1).

---

Addition: 
When going the way for 1) you must make sure to load mysqlnd and pdo_mysql from your php.ini and mysqlnd has to be first!
So somehing like

```
extension=mysqlnd.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

at the end of your php.ini might work

Comment: I had to remove `libmysql` because `mariadb` was complaining for conflicts. I am trying option 1) right now and will provide feedback along the process!

Comment: Added the lines to the `php.ini`. `phpize` complained, I renamed the `config9.m4`. Reached the `make` step and got this message: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. The `configure` step ends with and error: `configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>`.

Comment: I checked the `mysqlnd` directory after the `configure` and there are three files named `Makefile`: `Makefile.fragments`, `Makefile.global`, `Makefile.objects`.

Comment: Well, as said all this isn't really supported. Ane easy fix might be to remove the ssl related things from config[9].m4 and re-run phpize ... or you might remove all of rpm-installed PHP and try a full PHP build on your own (I don't know much about mariadb, but they have their client library, too, maybe option 2) still works )

Comment: I don't need a custom build, just the `pdo` drivers for `mysql`. Thanks for suggestion! Still trying to find a way...

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the configure file. The paths are coded incorrectly.

Replace 'ext/mysqlnd/' with '../../ext/mysqlnd/' in the .h files.

Comment: No! Don't do this! Then it might compile but not load!

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific? You mean: `ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.h`, `ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_libmysql_compat.h`, `ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_debug.h` and `ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h`? If yes, I'm trying right now!

Comment: See my answer for options

Comment: @johannes In order for your way to work, F. Gran needs to modify the configure file with the following lines of code:

    $PHP_OPENSSL="yes"

Otherwise, mysqlnd will complain about not being able to find OpenSSL's evp.h library

Comment: `make` on `mysqlnd` just complained saying: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`. Should I edit the `configure` generate inside the `mysqlnd` directory?

Comment: @F.Gran in the ext/mysqlnd directory rename the config9.m4 to config.m4. Run 'phpize', Then add the line of code to the configure file $PHP_OPENSSL="yes" around line 4330 or so. Then run ./configure. 
The error you're getting is because PHP_OPENSSL is never set in the script.

Comment: Trying now, will respond back in a second.

Comment: Not sure where should I actually place it. Placed it right before:  `test -z "$PHP_OPENSSL" && PHP_OPENSSL=no` and during the `./configure` returns the same error.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo: PHP_OPENSSL="yes". Where you put it should work, but I put it at the top of the file

Comment: It now worked and then I ran `make` but another error showed up: `/php 5.6.21/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_ps_codec.c:27:47: error: ext/mysqlnd/mysql_float_to_double.h: No such file or                                                  directory make: *** [mysqlnd_ps_codec.lo] Error 1`. Do you mind if we move this to chat? I really hope I can get the `pdo_mysql` to work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114266/discussion-between-kearney-taaffe-and-f-gran).

Answer (score 0):

please try this when you configure.

./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/your/php/bin/php-config --with-pdo-mysql=/path/to/your/mysql